# How to only play videoPreviewLayer when AVPlayer item is ".readyToPlay"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to achive the same thing that snapchat does. That is, when a user finishes taking a video and is taken to the preview view the video is kind of frozen for a second or so untill the video is ready to play, at that point it starts playing. I am trying to achive teh same. Bellow is what I have tried,

```
            while playerItem1.status == .unknown {
            print("1111121232432431243123241432143243214324321")
            if playerItem1.status == .readyToPlay {

                playerQueue = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: playerItem1)
                self.playerQueue?.play()

                playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: playerQueue)
                playerLayer.frame = (camPreview?.bounds)!
                playerLayer?.layoutIfNeeded()
                playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

                camPreview?.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, above: previewLayer)

                playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: playerQueue, templateItem: playerItem1)
            }
        }
```

however this lead the xcode to kind of crash because it seems to be never ending. Which I dont undertsand given that at some point status should become `.readyToPlay`, since if I leave it alone it does that.

Mainly I would like to do this because currently when you let go of teh capturebutton in my code teh screen freezes then it transitions. I want it to freez the video not the capture screen.

```
    extension ViewController: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
    //MARK: - Protocal stubs
    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAt fileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!) { print("bruh? MMMM") }

    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {
    }

    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {

        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error recording movie11: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            newViewVideoPlayback()

            switchIcon.isHidden = true
            switchWhiteUI.isHidden = true
            switchCamButton.isHidden = true
            camWhiteLine.isHidden = true

//            let videoRecorded = outputURL! as URL
//            playerItem1 = AVPlayerItem(url: videoRecorded)


            if !captureSession.isRunning {
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    self.startRunningCaptureSession()
                }
            }
        }

    }
    let videoRecorded = outputURL! as URL
    playerItem1 = AVPlayerItem(url: videoRecorded)

    playerItem1.addObserver(self,
    forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status),
    options: [.old, .new],
    context: &playerItemContext)

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                               of object: Any?,
                               change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                               context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        // Only handle observations for the playerItemContext
        guard context == &playerItemContext else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath,
                               of: object,
                               change: change,
                               context: context)
            return
        }

        if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status) {
            let status: AVPlayerItem.Status
            if let statusNumber = change?[.newKey] as? NSNumber {
                status = AVPlayerItem.Status(rawValue: statusNumber.intValue)!
            } else {
                status = .unknown
            }

            // Switch over status value
            switch status {
            case .readyToPlay:
            // Player item is ready to play.

                playerQueue = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: playerItem1)
                self.playerQueue?.play()

                playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: playerQueue)
                playerLayer.frame = (camPreview?.bounds)!
                playerLayer?.layoutIfNeeded()
                playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

                camPreview?.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, above: previewLayer)

                playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: playerQueue, templateItem: playerItem1)

            case .failed: break
            // Player item failed. See error.
            case .unknown: break
                // Player item is not yet ready.
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1389493-status)

> When a player item is created, its status is AVPlayerItem.Status.unknown, meaning its media hasn’t been loaded and has not yet been enqueued for playback. Associating a player item with an AVPlayer immediately begins enqueuing the item’s media and preparing it for playback. When the player item’s media has been loaded and is ready for use, its status will change to AVPlayerItem.Status.readyToPlay. You can observe this change using key-value observing.

So you need to listen to state instead of making a while loop that can overwhelm the system until the state changes , That's also in [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/responding_to_playback_state_changes)

```
private var playerItemContext = 0
playerItem.addObserver(self,
                           forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status),
                           options: [.old, .new],
                           context: &playerItemContext)

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
       of object: Any?,
       change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
       context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    // Only handle observations for the playerItemContext
    guard context == &playerItemContext else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath,
                           of: object,
                           change: change,
                           context: context)
        return
    }

    if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status) {
        let status: AVPlayerItemStatus
        if let statusNumber = change?[.newKey] as? NSNumber {
            status = AVPlayerItemStatus(rawValue: statusNumber.intValue)!
        } else {
            status = .unknown
        }

        // Switch over status value
        switch status {
        case .readyToPlay:
            // Player item is ready to play.
        case .failed:
            // Player item failed. See error.
        case .unknown:
            // Player item is not yet ready.
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
extension ViewController: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
    //MARK: - Protocal stubs
    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAt fileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!) { print("bruh? MMMM") }

    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {
    }

    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {

        if (error != nil) {
            print("Error recording movie11: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            newViewVideoPlayback()

            switchIcon.isHidden = true
            switchWhiteUI.isHidden = true
            switchCamButton.isHidden = true
            camWhiteLine.isHidden = true

             let videoRecorded = outputURL! as URL
             playerItem1 = AVPlayerItem(url: videoRecorded)
              playerItem1.addObserver(self,
              forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status),
              options: [.old, .new],
              context: &playerItemContext) 
              playerQueue = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: playerItem1)

            if !captureSession.isRunning {
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    self.startRunningCaptureSession()
                }
            }
        } 
    } 
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                           of object: Any?,
                           change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                           context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        // Only handle observations for the playerItemContext
        guard context == &playerItemContext else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath,
                               of: object,
                               change: change,
                               context: context)
            return
        }

        if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status) {
            let status: AVPlayerItem.Status
            if let statusNumber = change?[.newKey] as? NSNumber {
                status = AVPlayerItem.Status(rawValue: statusNumber.intValue)!
            } else {
                status = .unknown
            }

            // Switch over status value
            switch status {
            case .readyToPlay: 
                playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: playerQueue)
                playerLayer.frame = (camPreview?.bounds)!
                playerLayer?.layoutIfNeeded()
                playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill 
                camPreview?.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, above: previewLayer) 
                playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: playerQueue, templateItem: playerItem1) 
                // Player item is ready to play. 
                self.playerQueue?.play(
            case .failed: break
            // Player item failed. See error.
            case .unknown: break
                // Player item is not yet ready.
            }
        }
   } 
}
```

Comment: So it works but it does noyt fix teh problem... see this and if u fix it I can upvote this quation and you get teh other as well....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53644670/how-to-instantly-see-new-video-layer-after-letting-go-of-button